# How to sort the columns with below requirement

Tags: linux, vim, awk, sed

I have 3 columns

```
a 03 w
a 10 x
a 01 y
b 20 w
b 01 x
c 02 w
c 10 y
c 12 z
```

Expected output is

```
a 10 x
b 20 w
c 12 z
```

i.e. i need to sort column 2 but without changing the order of column 1
then grep the line with max value in the list based on 2nd column

Comment: some formatting might be helpfull.

Comment: Is column 1 always grouped together? If not, your requirement of not changing the order of column becomes a lot harder.

Comment: No requirement for keeping column1 grouped together until Expected output can be obtained

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches (choose one you like):

**1**) ***sort*** + ***uniq*** "trick":

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2rn file | uniq -w1
```

- `-k1,1` - sort lines by the 1st field on 1st phase
- `-k2,2rn` - sort lines by the 2nd field numerically in reversed order
- `uniq -w1` - output unique lines comparing no more than `1` character in lines (can be adjustable `-w<number>`)

The output:

```
a 10 x
b 20 w
c 12 z
```

---

**2**) Simply with GNU ***datamash*** tool:

```
datamash -Wsf -g1 max 2 <file | cut -f1-3
```

The output:

```
a   10  x
b   20  w
c   12  z
```

Answer (score 1):

***Input***

```
$ cat infile
a 03 w
a 10 x
a 01 y
b 20 w
b 01 x
c 02 w
c 10 y
c 12 z
```

***Output***

```
$ awk -F'[[:blank:]]' '{f=($1 in b)}f && b[$1]<$2 || !f{a[$1]=$0;b[$1]=$2}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' infile
a 10 x
b 20 w
c 12 z
```

***Better Readable***

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]' '
                     {
                       f=($1 in b)
                     }
                     f && b[$1]<$2 || !f{
                        a[$1]=$0;
                        b[$1]=$2
                     }
                  END{
                        for(i in a)
                            print a[i]
                     }
                    ' infile
```

***Explanation***

- `-F'[[:blank:]]'` - Set Input Field Separator
- `f=($1 in b)` - variable `f` holds boolean status (`true=1/false=0`), depending on whether index/array key (`$1`) exists in array `b`
- `f && b[$1]<$2 || !f` if `f` is true and array(`b[$1]`) value is less than (`< $2`) current row/record/line's 2nd column value, or (`||`) `!f` meaning array does not have key which we looked for then
- `a[$1]=$0;` array (`a`) with index key being first column(`$1`) of current line holds entire line/row/record (`$0`)
- `b[$1]=$2` array (`b`) with index key being first column(`$1`) of current line holds 2nd field value (`$2`)
- `END { for(i in a)  print a[i] }`  END block loop through array `a` and print array values.

> **Note :** Please modify `-F'...'` accordingly, to match your file field separator

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UNIX commands `sort` and `awk`:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr file | awk '!seen[$1]++'
```

To apply them to the buffer in vim:

```
:!%sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr | awk '\!seen[$1]++'
```

Explanation:

The sort command will sort in input in to levels, first on column 1 and then on column 2. That gives you the following intermediate output:

```
a 10 x
a 03 w
a 01 y
b 20 w
b 01 x
c 12 z
c 10 y
c 02 w
```

We pipe that to a little `awk` script which maintains an array variable `seen` which is indexed by column 1. Since the logic is reverted by `!`, once we've *seen* column 1 before, we won't print it again:

```
a 10 x  <-- print
a 03 w
a 01 y
b 20 w  <-- print
b 01 x
c 12 z  <-- print
c 10 y
c 02 w
```

Answer (score 1):

try following too once.

```
awk '
{
  b[$1]=a[$1]>$2?(b[$1]?b[$1]:$0):$0;
  a[$1]=a[$1]>$2?a[$1]:$2;
}
END{
  for(i in a){
     print b[i]
}
}
'   Input_file
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk '
{                                    ##Starting block here.
  b[$1]=a[$1]>$2?(b[$1]?b[$1]:$0):$0;##creating an array named b whose index is $1, then checking if array a with index $1 value is greater than $2 or not, if yes then assign b[$1] to b[$1] else change it to current line. This is to make sure always we should get the line whose $2 value is greater than its previous value with respect to $1.
  a[$1]=a[$1]>$2?a[$1]:$2; ##creating an array named a whose index is $1 and checking if value of a[$1] is greater than $2 is yes then keep a[$1] value as it is else change its value to current line value.
}
END{                       ##Starting END block of awk here.
  for(i in a){             ##Starting a for loop to traverse inside array a elements.
     print b[i]            ##Because array a and array b have same indexes and we have to print whole lines values so printing array b value here.
}
}
'  Input_file              ##mentioning the Input_file here.
```